# React infinite loop in useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a `useEffect()` which should be called once but continuously it is calling the getStories method.

```
const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(1);
const [recordsPerPage, setrecordsPerPage] = useState(5);
const { jwt } = useSelector((state: StateParams) => state.account);

useEffect(() => {
  if (jwt) {
    dispatch(
      getStories({ token: jwt, pageNo: pageNo, recordsPerPage: recordsPerPage })
    );
  }
}, []);
```

UPDATED: I feel flatlist is causing

```
<FlatList
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 14,
                        alignSelf: "stretch"
                    }}
                    data={Items}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
const renderItem = useCallback(({ item } : {id: string}) => {
        console.log({item})
        const Section = Components[item.id]
        return (<Section {...props}/>)
    }, [Items])
```

Comment: How did you know that it is calling infinite times ? Add console.log insided useEffect ,and check it once .

Comment: Yes, did the same as well. I can see it is calling continuously

Comment: what does getStories return ? Object right ?

Comment: const dispatch = useDispatch(),

Comment: @copycat I think the problem comes from a parent component that have an infinite loop, please share the parent of this component ^^

Comment: your code should run 1, the problem may come from parent. check your parent component or share your code pls

Comment: yes, flatlist is making this to happen. 
<FlatList
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 14,
                        alignSelf: "stretch"
                    }}
                    data={items}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />